# Parsing obligatory parameter with colon using getopts

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

Is there possibility to parse obligatory argument containing colon using **getopt** in bash?

Let's say I've prepared code like below:

```sh
    while getopts "qt:i:" arg; do
        case "$arg" in
             :)
                HOST=$(printf "%s\n" "$1"| cut -d : -f 1)
                PORT=$(printf "%s\n" "$1"| cut -d : -f 2)
                shift 1
                ;;
            -q)
                QUIET=1
                shift 1
                ;;
            -t)
                TIMEOUT="$2"
                if [ "$TIMEOUT" = "" ]; then break; fi
                shift 2
                ;;
            -i)
                INTERVAL="$2"
                if [ "$INTERVAL" = "" ]; then break; fi
                shift 2
                ;;
            -h)
                usage 0
                ;;
            *)
                echoerr "Unknown argument: $1"
                usage 1
                ;;
        esac
    done
```

Full code can be found here: https://pastebin.com/1eFsG8Qn

How i call the script:

```
wait-for database:3306 -t 60 -i 10
```

Problem is that this logic can't parse HOST_URL:PORT.
Any tips how to parse it?

Comment: That's a colon, not a semicolon. The problem is that `getopts` stops parsing as soon as it finds something that doesn't start with a `-`.

Comment: Thanks for catching naming mistake:)

Does it mean that `getopts` will not work in that case?

Comment: Yes; if you want to allow positional arguments to precede options, you'll need to use something else (like GNU `getopt`), or parse the arguments yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there possibility to parse obligatory argument containing colon using getopt in bash?

Sure - they have to be after options.

```
wait-for -t 60 -i 10 database:3306
```

then:

```
while getopts .... ;do
    case ...
    blabla) .... ;;
    esac
done
shift "$(($OPTIND-1))"
printf "Connect to %s\n" "$1"      # here
```

The colon in argument is not anyhow relevant.

> Any tips how to parse it?

Use `getopt` - it reorders the arguments.

Comment: That would actually do the job.
Is there a way to keep the obligatory argument before the options?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash